# Access to the Path is denied when C#.NET windows app tries to create files on a windows 7 laptop. Working on Windows 7 desktop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pdf

We have written a `windows app` which is creating new temp files for Word, Excel, PPT and PDF.

It's working fine on windows 7 desktop which has Administrator ,UserName/Machine Name groups with Full control in Security tab.

It's not working on Windows 7 laptop having Administrators, Users (with no write access) and Authenticated Users group.It's only working for .txt files not working for `.doc, .xls, .ppt or .pdf` and giving below error

Is it some GROUP Policy or Patch or some security feature in Win 7 OS ?

Exception Message :Access to the path

> 'C:\Users\235307\Desktop\MDefineTest\Test.pdf' is denied.
>   Inner Exception :Null
>   StackTrace :at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>      at MDefinePDFPlugin.PDFLoader.checkIsDocOpen(String path)
>      at MDefinePDFPlugin.PDFLoader.CreateAnnotation(String fileName, String rootFolder)

Comment: Have you tried to change the file path other than desktop?

Comment: LAPTOP :File is placed locally on the laptop...it's only working for .txt files from any drive...it's not working for .doc, .pdf,.excel,.ppt from any drive or directory         DESKTOP: Working for all files and folders.

Comment: Is there any protection software that you can disable on the laptop ?

Comment: Is there any protection software that you can disable on the laptop ? According to your answers, it seems that something is preventing you to create files other than .txt. It could be a security software like an antivirus or something like that. It could also be a group policy on the system. You can check the active group policies to see. This link cold be interresting: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/844794-gpo-to-block-certain-file-types/

Answer (score 0):

It does not seems to be something related to your code since it is working at least on one machine.

You may be missing some authorizations to create the file you want.
You should check the permissions on the target folder/file and ensure that the user running the process is allowed to create your file. You can get the permissions on a folder by right-clicking on it > properties > permissions tab.

Comment: Yeah have checked that and even given full control to all the groups present in security tab. is it some group Policy ?